# find sublist within larger list on a TI-84+

Tags: ti-basic

I'm making snake using the TI basic on my calculator, and that works well and all. the sublist would always be 2 long.

I am aware of:

```
max(not(L1-X))
```

but this only checks for 1 value and I  need to check for the sublist {X,Y} not just X...

the issue is,  the larger you get, the slower the snake moves, because the list can get over 100 characters long.
the code that I'm using:

```
:0 -> T
:For(I,2,dim(L1)-2,2):
:(L1(I-1)=X)(L1(I)=Y) + T -> T
:if T ≥ 1:Then:1->P:End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store coordinates as [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) instead of pairs of adjacent numbers. Complex numbers intrinsically represent 2-dimentional values, so many of their operations map nicely to operations on 2D coordinates. For example instead of storing three coordinates (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2) as `{1,1,1,2,2,2}`, store them as `{1+1i,1+2i,2+2i}`.

To convert coordinates to complex numbers, you just need to use the imaginary unit, *i*, like `X+Yi`.

To extract the coordinates from a list element `I`, you can take the real and imaginary parts of the element, `real(L1(I))→X` and `imag(L1(I))→Y`.

You can check for inclusion of a coordinate in a list of complex numbers using a modified version of the trick you mentioned, `max(not(abs(L1-(X+Yi))))`. `abs` takes the magnitude of each complex number in the list `L1-(X+Yi)` which will be zero if and only if the components of the complex number are `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer answers the title question, however I think it is inferior to [my answer using complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76397709) for the full question.

You can find the index of an element in a list using `seq` and `SortD`. Then you can use `seq` again to get a sublist and compare with `=` and `min`.

For example:

```
:L₁=X→ʟPRED
:If max(ʟPRED):Then
:seq(I,I,1,dim(L₁),1)→ʟINDEX
:SortD(ʟPRED,ʟINDEX)
:ʟINDEX(1)→I
:seq(L₁(J),J,I,I+1,1)→ʟSUBL
:If min(ʟSUBL={X,Y}):Then
:"Do stuff"
:EndIf
:EndIf
```